# Swift 2 - NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData Handling Error

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

I have a JSONParser, but unfortunately I couldn't adapt `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error)` bit to Swift 2.0, so I am receiving error:

> `Extra argument 'error' in call`

I found out that I can achieve this with do-try-catch, but I couldn't figure out how to adapt it in my case. Whatever I tried is just throwing another error.

```
class JSONParser {

  let json: AnyObject?
  var error: NSError?

  init(data: NSData){  // ~this chunk~
      self.json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error)
  }

  func array()->NSArray?{
      if let jsonResponse: AnyObject = self.json{
          return jsonResponse as? NSArray
      }
      return nil
  }

  func dictionary()->NSDictionary?{
      if let jsonResponse: AnyObject = self.json{
          return jsonResponse as? NSDictionary
      }
      return nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**swift3**

`NSJSONSerialization` and its methods are modified, according to the [Swift Documents](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).

```
do {
  
    let JsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    // you can now use t with the right type        
    if let dictFromJSON = JsonDict as? [String:String]
 {
        // use dictFromJSON
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

**Swift2**

```
   init(data: NSData){  // ~this chunk~
     do {
        self.json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
   
     } catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
        self.json = nil
     }
  }
```

for more information [tutorial1](https://grokswift.com/swift2/), [tutorial2](http://natashatherobot.com/swift-2-0-try/)

Comment: When I tried your example, I receive `Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties`

Comment: @senty add `self.json = nil` to the `catch {}` block

Comment: @sbarow Solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
var dataSource = [AnyObject]()


do {  self.dataSource = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as! [AnyObject]
} catch let error as NSError {
print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

if self.dataSource.count != 0 {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.sampleTableView.reloadData()
     }

      }
```